# Create a catchall dynamic route in remix

Tags: reactjs, remix, remix.run

I'm using remix to serve my react application.
All my pages have dynamic slugs, therefore I need to find a way to resolve the following type of URL:
eg. mywebsite.com/dynamic_slug

If I create an $index.jsx file in the routes folder it works in that all the dynamic URLs resolve to that file, BUT, I can't seem to find a way to then read the slug in the compontent so that I serve the right data.

Many thanks to any responders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the dynamic params via the `params` object passed to your loaders and actions.

```
// routes/$index.jsx

export async function loader({request, params, context}) {
  const slug = params.index // whatever $name is
  //...
}
```

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/data-loading#route-params

Comment: To anyone else reading this, you can then access the data resolved from the loader function, with useLoaderData(); in your function to render the page (also requires useLoaderData to be imported).. the link provided in the answer by @kiliman has the info you'll need.